# NgFor wants an array

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Using Elasticsearch and Ng-Bootstrap Typeahead for autocomplete.

I'm getting this error in Chrome console:

```
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays
```

My data that gets returned from ES looks like this:

```
{
      "hits": {
        "total": 21,
        "hits": [
          {
            "_source": {
              "suggestions": "bruce willis"
            }
          },
          {
            "_source": {
              "suggestions": "bruce wayne"
            }
          },
          {
            "_source": {
              "suggestions": "bruce"
            }
          },
          {
            "_source": {
              "suggestions": "brian"
            }
          }
```

So I'm not exactly sure how to either adjust my autocomplete component or my ES service code to give NgFor the hits array, which only solves half the problem it seems because then the hits array is an array of objects. How do I then extract the value of `"suggestions"` from the `_source`?

Comment: Your service _must_ return an array and not an object.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource - any pointers on how to return an array in the service - I'm still learning Observables...